# inuit.css uneven image height on window resize

Tags: html, css, image

I am having a problem with my images when I resize the browser.

The layout is one hero image in the first row, in the second row are 3 images that are all 325px x 310px these images have no resizing problem.

In the third row are two pictures 660px x 310px and 325px x 310px. When I resize the browser window the images do not remain equal in height.  The wider image is about three pixels taller just before the change to mobile layout.

I am hoping that someone can shed some light on why the images are not remaining equal in height

Comment: Try to have an even width for both images. Otherwise please join a fiddle.

Comment: Make a fiddle with associated inuit

Answer (score 0):

In the absence of a fiddle to confirm this, I'd guess that it has to do with the responsive styles defined in inuit.css/bas/_images.scss:

```
img{
    max-width:100%;
}
```

Because your images are different widths, and the default height is `auto`, the displayed height of the images will change as width changes.

I'm guessing you have a max-height on the images, too, otherwise you'd be seeing a much more distinct difference in apparent height between these *very different* aspect ratios! I'm betting that when the page width shrinks enough, the natural height of the shorter/wider image edges under the max-height you've set.

The best solution here is to provide consistently sized images, as @kursus suggested; otherwise, you might consider putting a BG colour on the containing div, so that the *layout* looks right, even though the images are broken.

Check http://www.mademyday.de/css-height-equals-width-with-pure-css.html for excellent tips on the subject.